# Discard a specific commit when merge until new modification on the file

Tags: merge, commit, git-revert

Hello,

I have 2 branches on Github ("A" and "B" because I have 2 projects) and weekly, I merge "A" into "B" but not "B" into "A" (to keep "B" up-to-date).
Every day, I add new commits into "A".

I did a bad merge and I merged "B" into "A" but I reverted my commit.

Then, I created 2 new commits into "A".

Now, I would like to merge "A" into "B" but when Github compares the 2 branches, I see that if I merge "A" into "B", Github will overrides a plenty of files with the version from "A" (the last version) but I would like to keep the current version in "B".

Is there a way to merge "A" into "B" without the bad merge (a specific commit) and discard those specific files forever (until there is a new modification on it and then, I will merge)?

Per example, the version of a file in "B" is 5 and the version in "A" is 4.
Because I did a bad merge (merge "B" into "A"), now Github wants to merge the version 4 from "A" into "B" but I don't want until there is a new modification on that file and the version in "A" is 6, then I will merge into "B".

Thanks